# Sum of the series $1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+......2001^2-2002^2+2003^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Sum of the series $1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+......2001^2-2002^2+2003^2$

How to solve this series?

$(1^2+3^2+5^2+ \cdots +2003^2)-(2^2+4^2+6^2+ \cdots +2002^2)$

Now what to do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AP only: 
$$(1^2-0^2) + (3^2-2^2)+\ldots + (2003^2-2002^2)$$
$$=1\cdot 1 + 1\cdot 5 + \ldots + 1\cdot 4005$$
$$=1+5+9+\ldots + 4005 $$
$$= \ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^N (n+1) r^n = \dfrac{d}{dr} \sum_{n=0}^N r^{n+1}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^N (n+1)^2 r^n = \dfrac{d}{dr} \sum_{n=0}^N (n+1) r^{n+1} = \dfrac{d}{dr} \left(r \sum_{n=0}^N (n+1) r^n \right)$$